# what will happen if we signal semaphore without wait?

Tags: c++, multithreading

In my project when I was implementing I came across the scenario. I have a binary semaphore which is taken by one thread. when that thread executing, the semaphore is signaled multiple times by another thread. Is it an issue or will it cause any undefined behavior??

Answer (score 4):

It is an error to signal a semaphore without a corresponding wait. What happens if you do this is implementation dependent.

If a call to [ReleaseSemaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685071%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on a Windows Semaphore object would result in the maximum count being exceeded, `ReleaseSemaphore` returns `FALSE`. It will not throw an exception or cause a fatal runtime error.

Under Linux, a call to [sem_post](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_post) that would exceed the maximum count returns -1, and `errno` is set to `EOVERFLOW`. Again, this will not be fatal to your application.

Under .NET, a call to [Release](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6caa9s64%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that would exceed the semaphore's maximum value results in `SemaphoreFullException` being thrown.

It's a logic error to release a semaphore more often than it's acquired. If your program does that, you have a latent bug. It might be okay in your particular situation, but if you try this with anything other than a binary semaphore, you're likely to end up with some very difficult to find bugs.

I would strongly recommend that you check the return value when you release the semaphore, and treat a failure as a fatal exception.

Comment: Thank you for your 'to the point' answer. Every other answer I can find on the internet just says 'You shouldn't do it' but doesn't really answer the question which pops up while learning the two types of semaphores!

Answer (score 0):

A binary semaphore is called a Mutex.

Nothing will happen, the mutex can either be taken or not taken, those are the only two states. Releasing a non acquired mutex has no negative effects.

However, take into account the *logic* may be affected. It doesn't seem like you're controlling too well when and how you signal the mutex, which may result on you releasing the mutex that another thread has acquired.

Comment: The semantics of a binary semaphore and a mutex are different.